# How to write java code REST Assured code to get authorization token?

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured

I need to create tests using RestAssured - Java for testing REST API. In order to get an authentication token (OAuth 2.0), I need to send from postman request filled as in the screen below. However, in java tests, I can not use postman. Any idea how it should look like java code to get authentication token?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do **note/store clientid and secret** that you get from uaa server:

Then First try to call uaa for tokens :

```
    Response response =
         given()
.header("Authorization",<client id>:<client secret>)
.contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.formParam("grant_type","authorization_code")                                                   .formParam("redirect_uri",REDIRECT_URL)
.formParam("response_type","code")
.formParam("code", AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
.formParam("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
.formParam("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
        .when()
 .post(BASE_URI+"/oauth2/token");
```

Then Fetch out information of access token and token type like below:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString());
    String accessToken = jsonObject.get("access_token").toString();
    String tokenType = jsonObject.get("token_type").toString();
    log.info("Oauth Token with type " + tokenType + "   " + accessToken);
```

Lastly call your endpoint by passing access token in **header**:

```
Response response =
      given()
          .headers(
              "Authorization",
              "Bearer " + accessToken,
              "Content-Type",
              ContentType.JSON,
              "Accept",
              ContentType.JSON)
          .when()
          .get(url)
          .then()
          .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
          .extract()
          .response();
```

Comment: Thanks Pramod, I think it is a good point to start, but what I should enter for AUTHORIZATION_CODE. I mean on this line in your comment: 
formParam("code", AUTHORIZATION_CODE). 
Take a look at my screenshot. What value I should enter instead of AUTHORIZATION_CODE?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an algorithm/snippet of how your code should look like:

**Prerequisites:**

1. Initial OAuth token and clientID should be taken and stored (in a DB or any data
   storage).
2. Time of OAuth token generation must be stored
3. Refresh token must be stored.
4. Validity (For how long the current OAuth token is valid) of OAuth token must be known/stored.

**Algorithm:**

```
 long validityOfOAuthToken = DB.get ("validityOfOAuthToken");
 long OAuthGeneratedTimeInMillis = DB.get ("oAuthGeneratedTime");
 long currentTimeInMillis = DateTime.now (DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis ( );
 if (currentTimeInMillis - OAuthGeneratedTimeInMillis > validityOfOAuthToken)
 {
    String clientID = DB.get ("clientID");
    String refreshToken = DB.get ("refreshToken");
    String accessToken = generateAccessToken (clientID, refreshToken); // API Invocation to get access token via refresh token
    DB.save ("oauthToken", accessToken);
    DB.save ("oAuthGeneratedTime", DateTime.now (DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis ( ));
    return accessToken;
 }
 else
 {
    return DB.get ("oauthToken");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .
Using `"client_secret"` and `"client_id"` it creates a `bearerToken` and later we can use it to authenticate.

```java
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://coop.apps.symfonycasts.com/";
RestAssured.basePath = "/token";

// client_secret is different from oauth2 token
Response response = given()
            .formParam("client_id","samapp")
            .formParam("client_secret","f56f459193cee56817c2a99c205654b7")
            .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials").post("");

//To get token
String bearerToken = response.jsonPath().get("access_token");

System.out.println("The bearer token value is "+bearerToken);

Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode(),"Status code mismatches");
```

Comment: Hi, please explain briefly what your code is supposed to do, even though it's clean enough!

Comment: Using client_secret and client_id It creates a bearerToken and later we can use it authenticate ,directly .

Comment: I'll just edit your post with your additional description and some slight code formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
public class AuthenticationUtils {

    public static String generateOAuth2Token() {
        return "Bearer "+RestAssured.given().auth().basic("{YOUR_USERNAME}", "{YOUR_PASSWORD}")
                .formParam("client_id", "{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}")
                .formParam("client_secret", "{YOUR_SECRET}")
                .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .formParam("{ANY_OTHER_TOKEN_NAME}", "{TOKEN_VALUE}")
                .formParam("redirect_uri", "{http://take-me-here-next.com/api/endpoint}")
                
                .when().post("https://{YOUR_TOKEN_URL}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .then()
                .extract().path("access_token");
        
    }
```

}

substitute values within {} with your's

Answer (score 0):

Grant type in question posted is Authrization code but everyone replied for client credential